# How does one Install a Brother HL-2270DW Laser Printer on Arch Linux ARM and Raspberry Pi 4B?

Tags: drivers, raspberry-pi, network-printer, arm, cups

How to Install a Brother HL-2270DW Laser Printer on Arch Linux ARM and Raspberry Pi 4B?

I can rarely find a solution to Arch Linux ARM 4.19 integration and implementation issues. This is a self-answered question for future reference. I am sharing my solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The current Arch Linux ARM version does not include an install of CUPS that is used to run and manage the network printers. Use `pacman` as below to install the original CUPS and include PDF printers:

```
sudo pacman -S cups cups-pdf
```

Enable and start the cups services using the following commands.

```
systemctl enable org.cups.cupsd 
systemctl start org.cups.cupsd
```

Navigate to your build directory, a place where you can sandbox your code and download files. Execute the following commands to download and build the Brother's printers driver.

```
git clone https://github.com/pdewacht/brlaser.git
cd brlaser
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

You should now be able to start the CUPS interface by pasting `localhost:631` into you browser, similar to the illustration below.

[image: CUPS User Interface in Browser]

Click on the Administration Tab then click on Add Printer on the following page. A list of printers and virtual printers should appear with your printer in the list, as illustrated below.

[image: My Discovered Printer]

In my case after clicking the Continue button on the list page, my printer driver was listed at the top as illustrated below.

[image: Illustration of brlaser drivers with default selected]

I left all the default option and just clicked the Continue buttons. Once configuration completed, the printer information looks like the following:

[image: Brother HL-2270DW Laser Printer Information]

---

The other models also supported by this solution are:

DCP-1510 series, DCP-1600 series, DCP-7030, DCP-7040, DCP-7055, DCP-7055W, DCP-7060D, DCP-7065DN, DCP-7080, DCP-L2500D series, DCP-L2520D series, DCP-L2540DW series, HL-1110 series, HL-1200 series, HL-2030 series, HL-2140 series, HL-2220 series, **HL-2270DW series**, HL-5030 series, HL-L2300D series, HL-L2320D series, HL-L2340D series, HL-L2360D series, MFC-1910W, MFC-7240, MFC-7360N, MFC-7365DN, MFC-7840W, MFC-L2710DW series, Lenovo M7605D

Comment: I tried this on a Rpi4 running Manjaro (I know...it is not Arch), and got the following error:  `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:94 (message):
  <cups/raster.h> header not found.  Are the CUPS development packages
  installed?`   

Did you get this error?  What other packages (besides `cups` and `cups-pdf`) did you install first to satisfy the CUPS dependencies?

Comment: The above comment concerns the `brlaser` portion of your post.

Comment: Since this `brlaser` is only a portion of what I installed on my ALARM system, I'm not sure if any of these other packages might have been a dependency (some I doubt are relevant). I've pasted those below that I installed that _might_ help with your problem and removed the apps like Chromium and Thunderbird, that I installed from this list. 
`pacman -S crda fuse-exfat i2c-tools nm-connection-editor network-manager-applet networkmanager numlockx patch wpa_supplicant wireless_tools pulseaudio-alsa pulseaudio-bluetooth bluez-utils libmm-glib modemmanager cups cups-pdf libvncserver`

Comment: @Rsync Check the 'brlaser' [source repo](https://github.com/pdewacht/brlaser). They suggest `libcups2-dev, libcupsimage2-dev or similar`